# Cordova captured video upload not working properly in android

Tags: android, html, cordova, video, html5-video

i have used this code for video upload to server.

IOS is working fine. Android is not working properly but some time showing. i m confusing, 
  i have used **options.mimeType="video/mp4" and options.mimeType="video/mpeg";**

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                               options.fileKey="file";
                               options.fileName = fvideos[i].vname;
                              //options.fileName=fimage[i].substr(fimage.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                               options.mimeType="video/mp4";
                               options.chunkedMode = false;
                           var ft = new FileTransfer();
                           ft.upload(fvideos[i].orginal.fullPath, encodeURI(base_url+"/datasend/"), function(response){
                                return response.data.data;
                           },function(error){
                            //alert("Error uploading Video");
                           // alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                           }, options);
                      }
```

web site :
 using **html5** video tag

```
  <video autobuffer controls autoplay>
  <source id="mp4" src="videoname.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

i got file name correctly and file uploded successfully. can u help?

> . Issue is only playing audio.video is not showing.